# Can't set background-image for a specific div

Tags: html, css, background-image

Some strange behavior about background image

**HTML**

```
<body>  

<div id="divGaLL">
<ul id="ulGaLL">
<li>...</li>
<li>...</li>
</ul>
</div>  

</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
    background:url(img/back01.jpg); //works
}

#divGaLL{
   background:red;  // works        
   background:url(img/back01.jpg);  //doesn't work
}

#ulGaLL{
    background:url(img/back01.jpg);  //works
}
```

Why I can't set **back01.jpg** as background for `#divGaLL`?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ please

Comment: Delete Browser history and try. If it doesn't solve then try with background:url('../img/back01.jpg')
or 
background:url('~/img/back01.jpg')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you are using the same property and different values. When you are using `background:` you can write color and image in same line

```
#divGaLL{
   background:url(http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-scuba-diving-icon-set/128/fish.png) red;  
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ufYvA/1/)**

Answer (score 2):

You need to use

`background-image: url('img/back01.jpg');`

or e.g.

`background: red url('img/back01.jpg') left top no-repeat;`

Try to stick with this order of the "arguments" if possible ;)

I prefer to use the second way, however sometimes when you just need to change one thing it is better to use only the first approach.

It's always a good practice to define **height** and **width** and redeclare that this element is a **block** and not an inline style etc. if possible to prevent unwanted behaviour so use something like:

```
display: block;
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
background: red url('img/back01.jpg') left top no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `background` property is a shorthand for setting a bunch of properties, including `background-image`.  If you want to specify the background colour, or a background image, without overriding anything else, you should spell out `background-color` and `background-image` in full:

```
#divGaLL {
   background-color: red;  
   background-image: url(img/back01.jpg);
}
```

See ["background" on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background).

Answer (score 1):

if `#ulGaLL` has a background image which completely covers it then you wouldn't see the background of `#divGaLL`.

Comment: Excuse me, but I don't want the div to be red. The line `background:red;` is just for checking that the div is there. I whant only the background image in it.

Comment: I appreciate that, but my point is that if the `<ul>` has a full background (image or colour) that it could then hide any background (image or colour) applied to the `div`. without seeing more of your styles, or the images in question I can't be sure ahere the issue is.

Comment: Duncan, I tried to turn off the background of #ulGaLL - without result. #divGaLL remains without img background.

Comment: If you could recreate the problem using the minimal amount of code in http://jsfiddle.net/ then we would be able to help more, right now all we can do is guess.

Comment: [Here's a basic fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/duncan/aaURA/) with your code and some placeholders

Comment: Duncan, I see, you fiddle works and I copied this line: `background:url(http://lorempixel.com/50/50/);` - doesn't work in my file. I can do everything with that div, but cannot set bckg image.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
background:red url(img/back01.jpg) no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

```
#divGaLL{
    width:200px; /* Width of back01.jpg */
    height:200px; /* Height of back01.jpg */
    background-image:url('img/back01.jpg'); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you put the image in your HTML, u can use something like this:

```
#divGaLL img{ background-color:red;}
```

It will take only the IMG instead of the whole div.

And yes, do not only use background for a deffinition, since background is used for all kind of different things then only img or color.

So always use background-color, background-image or whatever you want with it

Comment: Hello people, listen this: I changed the id from `#divGaLL` to `#divGaLL3` - everything works. I changed back to `#divGaLL` - doesnt work. Each other name works - except `#divGaLL`. I HAVE NO OTHER DIVS ON FILE !

Comment: Weird that THAT was the problem.. But I am happy you found the problem yourself! :)